# How can I download DataFrame in the Fllask app by click on the button?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, flask

views.py

```
@mod.route('/report)
def report():
    #DataFrame
    df
    return render_page(df.to_html(), template="/report.html")
```

For Download I add to the view:

```
resp = make_response(df.to_csv())
    resp.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=export.csv"
    resp.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/csv"
    return resp
```

How can I check click on the button in flask app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have various dataframe in the various url.
I do:

```
@mod.route('/report', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def report:
    # DataFrame
    df
    if request.method == "POST":
        buffer = BytesIO()
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(buffer, engine="xlsxwriter")
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="scraped data")
        writer.save()
        buffer.seek(0)
        return send_file(buffer,
                    mimetype="application/vnd.ms-excel",
                    attachment_filename="report.xlsx",)
        return render_page(df.to_html(), description=name_reports[0], template="/report.html")
```

report.html

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"><button>Download</button></form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need two different endpoints to display the table and to offer the csv file for download.
For download, the data is written into a stream and then sent via [`send_file`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.send_file). By adding an anchor to your template, which refers to said endpoint and has the `download` attribute, you can make the file available for direct download.

```
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template, 
    send_file
)
import pandas as pd
import io

app = Flask(__name__)

df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]])

@app.route('/report')
def index():
    return render_template('report.html', table=df.to_html())

@app.route('/download')
def download():
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    df.to_csv(buffer)
    buffer.seek(0)

    return send_file(
        buffer, 
        as_attachment=True, 
        mimetype='text/csv', 
        download_name='export.csv'
    )
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Report</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="{{ url_for('download') }}" download>Download</a>
    {{ table | safe }}
</body>
</html>
```